# How to split a file in Hadoop?

Tags: linux, unix, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Wondering what path you guys would take in order to split a large file which happens to be in HDFS into separate chunks (of a preconfigured size)?

Thinking MapReduce would be helpful here and unsure whether a more vanilla Unix solution would work best.

(Needing to split files b/c seems that on our end Sqoop will not export files >~400GB)

Comment: what is the condition of the split ?

Comment: Line endings (\n, basically)... the size of the split files doesn't have to be exact